# Authorization Flow in backend-using auth0

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, microservices, auth0

Context- There is a web app, which allows login through Auth0. It has 2 types of memberships- membership 1 and membership 2. User has to purchase one of these to even access the services. But even then there are some additional services which are accessed by paying an extra premium. e.g. Service 1 can be accessed if you buy membership 1, service 1 & 2 both can be accessed if you pay membership 2. But there is some other Service 3 which irrespective of membership you have to pay the additional price for.
Now after user's login, how to authorize the user to make sure user can only access the services which are in his scope. Obviously every one of these services endpoints will be a protected api endpoint and thus will definitely require access token in header, but the client wanted to pass "service token" as well.
Can anyone please help me out in this flow, how should authorization work here. You can suggest your own flow as well. Btw we are using Auth0 as the Oauth2/oidc provider so if you can, can you also explain in that context as well.
Any direction would be helpful.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski hey i do not want the whole solution, not even one line of code that i will explore myself i instead want the flow. The industry practice, personal suggestions of how flow should look like. And not even the whole flow , a part of flow would work as well. This is more of an architect question rather than some coding homework question. Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you are using JWT my suggestion would be to add service subscription things in JWT payload. Example :  Service 1:  Yes, Service 2: No, Service 3: No. Verify JWT token and if it valid read the Payload and based the values you can either allow to access or not access the corresponding endpoints.

Comment: @arjunthota is their a possibility that user is able to manipulate that payload before sending to the server. MITM?

Comment: Validate JWT Signature before doing anything. If user manipulates any data in payload signature validation will fail. So we can detect if JWT is manipulated or not. I think my comments will answer your need.